# How to build and push a docker image in a Terraform Docker Provider by GCP Cloud Build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

#### References

[Terraform Docker Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs)

[Terraform Google Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs)

[GCP Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/overview)

#### Context Details

1. The deployemnt is done by CICD based on the GCP Cloud Build (and the cloud build service account has an 'owner' role for relevant projects).
2. Inside a 'cloudbuild.yaml' file there is a step with a 'hashicorp/terraform' worker an a command like 'terraform apply'.

#### Goal

To build and push a docker image into a GCP Artefact Registry, so that it can be used in a container optimised compute engine deployment in other TF resources.

#### Issue

As the Terraform Google Provider does not have resources to work with the Artefact Registry docker images, I have to use the Terraform Docker Provider.

The docker image is described as:

```
resource "docker_registry_image" "my_image" {
  name = "europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/${var.my_project_id}/my-docker-reg/my-vm-image:test"
  build {
    context = "${path.module}/image"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}
```

According to the comment [Creating and pushing a docker image to a google cloud registry using terraform](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/issues/189#issuecomment-900875286): `For pushing images, the only way to set credentials is to declare them at the provider level.`

Therefore the registry_auth block is to be provided as described in the [Terraform Docker Provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs#nestedblock--registry_auth).

On one hand, as described in the [GCP Artefact Registry authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication) `You do not need to configure authentication for Cloud Build`. So I use this for configuration (as it is to be executed under the Cloud Build service account):

```
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = "europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev"
  }
}
```

and the Cloud Build job (terraform step) failed with an error:

```
Error: Error loading registry auth config: could not open config file from filePath: /root/.docker/config.json. Error: open /root/.docker/config.json: no such file or directory

  with provider["registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker"],
  on my-vm-image.tf line 6, in provider "docker":
   6: provider "docker" {
```

as the Docker Provider mandatory would like to get some credentials for authentication...

So, another option is to try an 'access token' as descibed in the [comment](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/issues/189#issuecomment-900875286) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token).

The access token for the cloud build service account can be retrieved by a step in the cloud build yaml:

```
## Get Cloud Build access token
- id: "=> get CB access token =>"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      access_token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) || exit 1
      echo ${access_token} > /workspace/access_token || exit 1
```

and later used in the TF step as a variable value:

```
...
access_token=$(cat /workspace/access_token)
...
terraform apply -var 'access_token=${access_token}' ....
...
```

So the Terraform Docker Provider is supposed to be configured according to the example `gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev` from the [GCP Artefact Registry authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token):

```
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = "europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev"
    username = "oauth2accesstoken"
    password = var.access_token
  }
}
```

But the Cloud Build job (terraform step) failed again:

```
Error: Error pushing docker image: Error pushing image: unauthorized: failed authentication
```

#### Questions

So, if I dont' try any completely different alternative approach, how the Terraform Docker Provider works within the GCP Cloud Build? What is to be done for a correct authentication?

Answer (score 0):

> As the Terraform Google Provider does not have resources to work with the Artefact Registry docker images

First, I don't understand the above sentence. Here is [Google's Artifact Registry resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/artifact_registry_repository).

Second, why use `docker_registry_image`? Or even `docker` provider?

If you provide your service account with the right role (no need for full ownership, `roles/artifactregistry.writer` will do) then you can push images built by Cloud Build to Artifact Registry without any problem. Just set the image name to `docker` in the necessary build steps.

For example:

```
steps:
  - id: build
    name: docker
    args:
      - build
      - .
      - '-t'
      - LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO/IMAGE
  - id: push
    name: docker
    args:
      - push
      - LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_ID/ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO/IMAGE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, my statement, which you did not understand, is absolutley correct at the present moment. The link you provided - describes Terraform resources (by Google as a provider) to work with the Artifact Registry as a service, rather than to work with (docker) images maintained by the Artifact Registry service.

Comment: Coming tot he second part - thank you very much again. That workaround is well known for a few years... It has plenty of issues from my point of view, thus I submitted the above question.

Comment: What would you like to do with the images that you cannot do right now?