# How can I retrieve the Docker images from Google Artifact Registry with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-artifact-registry

In the past I've manage to get the latest image from the Google Container Registry like this:

```
provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = "eu.gcr.io"
    username = "oauth2accesstoken"
    password = "${data.google_client_config.default.access_token}"
  }
}

data "google_container_registry_image" "myapp_tagged" {
  name    = "app"
  region  = "eu"
  project = var.project_id
  tag     = "latest"
}

data "docker_registry_image" "myapp" {
  name = "${data.google_container_registry_image.myapp_tagged.image_url}"
}

data "google_container_registry_image" "myapp" {
  region = "eu"
  name   = "${local.server_name}"
  digest = "${data.docker_registry_image.myapp.sha256_digest}"
}

output "docker_latest_image_url" {
  value = data.google_container_registry_image.myapp.image_url
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the latest image that are stored in Google Artifact Registry

My initial guess was replacing "google_container_registry_image" with "google_artifact_registry_image", but according to [Terraform google module documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/artifact_registry_repository) this doesn't exist.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Not, it's not so immediate. It's very similar but artifact registry can host more type of object that Containers. That's why you have to rework your TF. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/artifact_registry_repository

Comment: I don't know if there were any updates since last summer, but it may be interesting to read the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421246/how-to-build-and-push-a-docker-image-in-a-terraform-docker-provider-by-gcp-cloud - it is  a question how to push... As I understand, the link you provided - describes Terraform resources (by Google as a provider) to work with the Artifact Registry as a service, rather than to work with (docker) images maintained by the Artifact Registry service.

Comment: On my CI/CD pipelines I wanna use cloudbuild to create and push the image to Artifact registry (this step already works) and then use terraform to update my cloud run with the newest image. The image url doesn't change with the "latest" tag so it won't trigger changes to the cloud run. I need to get the url with the sha256 from Artifact registry but terraform doesn't seems to have a way to do it. @al-dann thanks for the resource but it doesn't fit my case as the url can't be fixed.

Comment: I would be glad if somebody can provide an answer how to pull (your question), or push (my original question a year ago from the link), by using _Terraform_, as, from the best of my understanding, - "Terraform allows to work with the Artifact Registry as a service, rather than to work with (docker) images maintained by the Artifact Registry service" - following the link provided by Guillaume.

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, we could only pull images using [Docker](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#pulling) or [`crictl`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#pull-crictl).

I would suggest filing a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) or submit a new issue through [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues) however it's not a guarantee that this would be immediately be available in the future but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.

Answer (score 0):

*This solution was suggested by user [salrashid123 on GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6635#issuecomment-647858867).*

If the goal is to get the sha256 related to a tag, it seems to be working this way with the [docker provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/kreuzwerker/docker/latest/docs):

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {}
  required_version = ">= 1.2.7"
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "3.0.2"
    }
  }
}
    
data "google_client_config" "default" {}

provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address  = "[YOUR DOCKER REPO URL]"
    username = "oauth2accesstoken"
    password = data.google_client_config.default.access_token
  }
}

data "docker_registry_image" "get_metadata" {
  name = "europe-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/<REPO_NAME>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>"
}

output "sha256_digest" {
  value = data.docker_registry_image.get_metadata.sha256_digest
}
```

To find your docker repository URL:

- Open GCP Artifact Registry
- Select one of your Docker Repository
- Click on `SETUP INSTRUCTION`

GCP will provide you the correct URL you're looking for.

Another simpler way is to use a data external and the gcloud cli :

```
data "external" "gcloud_get_digest" {
  program = [
    "gcloud", "artifacts", "docker", "images", "describe", local.full_image_tag, "--format", local.gcloud_format
  ]
}

locals {
  # Inputs to the external command
  full_image_tag = "europe-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/<REPO_NAME>/<IMAGE>:<TAG>"
  # data external requires the output format to be a json of string key/value pair
  gcloud_format = "value(format('{{\"digest\":\"{0}\"}}', image_summary.fully_qualified_digest))"
  # the .digest attribute comes from the line above where we manually create the json output
  full_image_digest = data.external.gcloud_get_digest.result.digest
}
```

This approach eliminates the need to manage the Docker provider, but note that using `program` should always be your last option, [as advised by HashiCorp itself](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external) :

> This mechanism is provided as an "escape hatch" for exceptional situations where a first-class Terraform provider is not more appropriate.