# 401 Unauthorized error while attempting to pull a docker image off gcr.io using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcr.io

First: I am very new to GCP, Terraform so pardon me if this is a dumb question / has been answered before. I have tried googling for it and havent got anywhere.

I am trying to pull a docker image from gcr.io to refer to its SHA. In my terraform scripts, I am hoping to deploy to Cloud Run when the SHA changes - the actual build happens in my Github Actions outside of Terraform. But when the action fires, I get a 401 Unauthorized error! The rest of the terraform actions with google provider resources work fine.

Note: my registry is private.

In order to achieve this, I am using the package kreuzwerker/docker: Pasting relevant sections of my scripts here:

Terraform script:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        google = {
            source = "hashicorp/google"
            version = "~> 5.0"
        }
        cloudflare = {
            source  = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
            version = "~> 4.0"
        }    
        docker = {
            source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
            version = "~> 3.0"
        }
    }
}

...

provider "docker" {
    registry_auth {
        address  = "gcr.io"
        username = "oauth2accesstoken"
        password = data.google_client_config.current-user.access_token
    }
}

... 

data "docker_registry_image" "backend_services_image_metadata" {
    name = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/${var.repo-name}:${var.repo-tag}"
}

data "google_container_registry_image" "backend_services_image_data" {
    name   = var.services-image-repo-name
    digest = data.docker_registry_image.backend_services_image_metadata.sha256_digest
}

...
```

When i execute this script, I get the following error:

`Error: Got error when attempting to fetch image version project-XXXX/repo-XXXX:latest from registry: Bad credentials: 401 Unauthorized`

I expected this to work and return me a SHA

Comment: Your registry is private, it means only authenticated and authorized requester can access it. So, is your github action script is authorized to pull the image?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes.  data.google_client_config.current-user.access_token should return an access token for a service-account that has read access to the artifact registry.

Comment: Did you try with an hardcoded token to validate the flow? You have a 401, the current identity is not authorized, maybe not the correct account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that is a brilliant idea. I tried it -and got a 401 error as well. So i then manually pasted in the access token for my personal account - which literally has the "owner" access in IAM, and it STILL gave me the same error. So now i am completely lost :(

Comment: Do you use artifact registry or container registry? If artifact registry, can you review your latest "data" line, it's a container registry definition. And the wrong API should be used

Comment: I am unsure what other APIs i could use - but in my research, google_container_registry_image also (sholud) work for artifact registry. I am indeed using artifact registry. See this question for a similar feedback. If you are aware of a different api i could try please do let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76315331/how-can-i-retrieve-the-docker-images-from-google-artifact-registry-with-terrafor

Comment: No, container registry code does not work with artifact registry https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/google/services/containeranalysis/data_source_container_registry_image.go Exceptionnally in your case, it could work, but I don't know the side effect. But can you clarify why you need to get the image from terraform? Only the reference is enough if you want to deploy your image (Cloud Run, GKE,...)

Comment: The challenge i am having is the Terraform scripts dont recognize that a new image has been pushed to the registry. So its not actually deploying it. I have since worked around it by passing in the Gihub SHA to the Terraform scripts instead of using :latest tagging. This is forcing the deployment. What i was trying to do with this solve was to dynamically pull the SHA from the repo and use that to do the deploy. that way the deploy would occur when the latest SHA changes and not otherwise. But my workaround works for now - still curious why there is no effective solve. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: When something is hard, unusual, not effective, (...) it's often because it's not the right pattern. In your case, you must implement this check outside terraform. Terraform is not made and design for that. That's why you have hard time to implement it!